# Android Studio 3.3 + android.arch.work:work-runtime causing compilation issues

Tags: android-jetpack, android-workmanager, android-studio-3.3

We were using 3.2 Android studio Along with Workmanager version 1.0.0.beta01. It was working fine.

After upgrading to 3.3 I got below compilation issue.

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

I tried upgrading workmanager version 1.0.0.beta02 also. It does not help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Google issue tracker, there seems to be a bug/change.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116154359

Add below lines in build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
}
```

Also add below lines in proguard file. I got few alerts from Guava while generating release build.

```
-dontwarn com.google.common.base.**
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.annotations.**
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```